# python complete json objects in file from another json file

Tags: python, json

I have two json file: file1.json and file2.json successively created.
I would like to complete file1 by adding the data of file2 for each object. Objects are exactly of the same number and have all same attributes

File 1 and 2 have strictly identical structure :
lists in file1 (open, close, ...) will be appended with values in file2, attributes like deltasum, detlatot would be changed with the values in file2.

```
[{"symbol": "AUDUSD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]}, {"symbol": "AUDNZD=X", …
```

I have tried dumps style but I can't rebuild the file as I want.
Thanks a lot guys for your support or ideas.

Comment: you have to use for-loop to add every element separatelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumes you have the same symbols in both lists, and symbols are in the same order on list.

You can use `for`-loop with `zip()` to work with rows from first and second as pair.

And later you can use `.extend` or `+=` to add all values from  one list to another.

```py
a = [
    {"symbol": "AUDUSD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDNZD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
]

b = [
    {"symbol": "AUDUSD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDNZD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
]

for a_row, b_row in zip(a, b):
    
    # extend lists
    #a_row['open'].extend( b_row['open'] )
    a_row['open']  += b_row['open']
    a_row['close'] += b_row['close']
    a_row['high']  += b_row['high']
    a_row['low']   += b_row['low']
    a_row['timestamp'] += b_row['timestamp']
    a_row['volume']    += b_row['volume']
    # ... etc.
    
    # replace values
    a_row['deltasum'] = b_row['deltasum']
    a_row['deltatot'] = b_row['deltatot']
    # ... etc.
    
import pprint
pprint.pprint(a)
```

---

You can make it shorter if you use inner `for`-loops

```py
a = [
    {"symbol": "AUDUSD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDNZD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
]

b = [
    {"symbol": "AUDUSD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDNZD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
]

for a_row, b_row in zip(a, b):
    
    # extend lists
    for key in ['open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'timestamp', 'volume']:  # ... etc. ...
        #a_row[key].extend( b_row[key] )
        a_row[key] += b_row[key]
    
    # replace values
    for key in ['deltasum', 'deltatot']: # ... etc. ...
        a_row[key] = b_row[key]
    
import pprint
pprint.pprint(a)
```

---

You can also get every `key,value` from row and use `isinstence()` to check if value is list or string - and run different function

```py
a = [
    {"symbol": "AUDUSD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDNZD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
]

b = [
    {"symbol": "AUDUSD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDNZD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
]

for a_row, b_row in zip(a, b):
    
    for key, value in b_row.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            # extend lists
            a_row[key] += value # b_row[key]
        else:
            # replace values
            a_row[key] = value # b_row[key]
    
import pprint
pprint.pprint(a)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If lists can be in different order then first you may need to sort them by symbol.

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda row:row['symbol'])

b = sorted(b, key=lambda row:row['symbol'])
```

But if lists may have different symbols then you may have to run nested loop:

```
for a_row in a:
    for b_row in b:
        if a_row['symbol'] == b_row['symbol']:
            if isinstance(value, list):
                # extend lists
                a_row[key] += value # b_row[key]
            else:
                # replace values
                a_row[key] = value # b_row[key]

            break  # don't need to compare current `a_row` with other `b_rows`
```

but this update only symbols which are in both lists. If you want to add new symbols from `b` to `a` and remove from `a` symbols which you don't have in `b` then it would need more complex code - and it could use `set()` to compare which symbols are only in one list.

```
a = [
    {"symbol": "AUDUSD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDNZD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDJPN=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
]

b = [
    {"symbol": "AUDUSD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDNZD=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
    {"symbol": "AUDEUR=X", "open": [0.72, 0.72], "close": [0.72, 0.72], "high": [0.72, 0.73], "low": [0.72, 0.73], "timestamp": [1647262622, 1647262682], "volume": [0, 0], "delta": [0.0, 0.0], "deltasum": 2.839999999999999, "deltatot": 2.8022723967505714, "voltot": 0, "cmfs": [0, 0, 0, 0], "mfms": [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0], "resist": [0, 0, 0]},
]

a_symbols = [row['symbol'] for row in a]
b_symbols = [row['symbol'] for row in b]

a_symbols = set(a_symbols)
b_symbols = set(b_symbols)

only_in_a = a_symbols - b_symbols
only_in_b = b_symbols - a_symbols

print('only_in_a:', only_in_a)
print('only_in_b:', only_in_b)
```

Result:

```
only_in_a: {'AUDJPN=X'}
only_in_b: {'AUDEUR=X'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Works perfectly. Used the last option.

Comment: I spoke too fast, the symbols might not be in the same order. Therefore, a line must be added to make sure that addons are done are the right place: I have added, '''if a_row["symbol"] == value:''' after the 2nd loop, but it does not work

Comment: if they can be in different order then you may try to sort them by symbol `a = sorted(a, key=lamba x:x["symbol'})` and the same for `b`. Or you whould have to create two nested `for`-loop `for a_row in a: for b_row in b: 'if a_row["symbol"] == b_row["symbol"]:` to compare every pairs of rows. Second version can be needed if some symbol may exists only in one dictionary.

Comment: I added some of informations in answer.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot